# Configuring a paid membership with subscriptions website with commerce module

Tags: commerce

I'm struggling in finding out a solution to provide membership access on my website with subscriptions renewed automatically depending which product/license they bought: 1-month membership, 3-month membership or 6-month membership.

After a few days of research I am trying to implement *Drupal Commerce 2.x Module*, following exactly these steps: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/recurring/getting-started.

So I've configured the payment gateway, the billing schedule, created the product variations as in images shown below, but I can't edit the products to work as a license type, because I receive this error:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So, the workflow would be like this:
1. Users registering accounts
2. Users buying appropriate product: 1-month, 3-month or 6-month membership 
3. Users got access based on membership role to premium content